# Need to retrieve a dynamic list element by its index

Tags: python, list

I'm working with a modem, so everything that gets sent for or by the modem gets appended to my list.

The thing I must retrieve is already inside this list, but if I try to print it by the index, it returns me error saying that the list doesn't have that element.

I get why the error occur, since my list begins empty, and ends up with 7 elements.

I tried to create a new assist variable, but I'm having no progress up until now.

The code part:

```
if (e == 'SBDRING'):  #change to format code

        print ('Ring Alert recebido')
        lido = True
        ser.write(str.encode('AT+SBDIX\r'))
        time.sleep(5)
        ser.write(str.encode('AT+SBDRT\r'))
        time.sleep(2)
        lista = []
        assistvar = 0
        while len(lista) < 10:
            u = ser.readline()
            i = u.rstrip()
            o = i.decode('utf-8')
            if len(o) > 1 :
                lista.append(o)
                assistvar = assistvar + 1
                print(lista)
                print('Lista size = ', len(lista))
                print('Assistvar = ', assistvar)
```

I know as a matter of fact that my message will be the second last element on my list. That's what I need to assign to a new variable, so I can program my popup with the message in question.

The output for the above code is:

```
Ring Alert recebido
['AT+SBDIX']
Lista size =  1
Assistvar =  1
['AT+SBDIX', '+SBDIX: 0, 196, 1, 126, 11, 5']
Lista size =  2
Assistvar =  2
['AT+SBDIX', '+SBDIX: 0, 196, 1, 126, 11, 5', 'OK']
Lista size =  3
Assistvar =  3
['AT+SBDIX', '+SBDIX: 0, 196, 1, 126, 11, 5', 'OK', 'AT+SBDRT']
Lista size =  4
Assistvar =  4
['AT+SBDIX', '+SBDIX: 0, 196, 1, 126, 11, 5', 'OK', 'AT+SBDRT', '+SBDRT:']
Lista size =  5
Assistvar =  5
['AT+SBDIX', '+SBDIX: 0, 196, 1, 126, 11, 5', 'OK', 'AT+SBDRT', '+SBDRT:', 'jupytertest']
Lista size =  6
Assistvar =  6
['AT+SBDIX', '+SBDIX: 0, 196, 1, 126, 11, 5', 'OK', 'AT+SBDRT', '+SBDRT:', 'jupytertest', 'OK']
Lista size =  7
Assistvar =  7
```

Which 'jupytertest' is what I must retrieve.

Changing the code to:

```
print(lista)
                    if assistvar > 6:
                        print(lista[5])
                        break
```

I get this output:

```
Ring Alert recebido
['AT+SBDIX']
['AT+SBDIX', '+SBDIX: 18, 198, 2, 0, 0, 0']
['AT+SBDIX', '+SBDIX: 18, 198, 2, 0, 0, 0', 'OK']
```

Thanks!

@edit:
Found a way with your help hehe. Using my assistvar, I was putting my looping to read the fifth element inside the looping to add any message with lenght greater than zero to my list. I took it out, and now I'm able to print only my message!

The edit on my code:

```
                if len(o) > 1 :
                    lista.append(o)
                    assistvar = assistvar + 1
                    print(lista)
                if assistvar == 7:
                    print(lista[5])
                    break
```

Comment: Please share the exact text of the error message and stack trace.

Comment: Will post it asap, but it's not a error message. If i take out the last 2 lines of the code, it prints the list I get with assistvar = 7. With the last 2 lines, it prints the list up until the 5 element, so assistvar = 4. I'm editing the comment in the next minutes with these messages. Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused. It seems contradictory to say both "it returns me error saying that the list doesn't have that element." and "it's not a error message". Is it an error or not? ... Or are you saying "my previous code raised an error, but now that I have `assistvar`, it doesn't raise an error any more."? If that's what you're saying, then what's the problem?

Comment: Sorry for that. Yes, I'm saying something more like your second sentence :) the error came as soon as I started this part of the code. The assistvar came to assist me with the error message, but it still doesn't print only the element I'm after through its index.

Comment: @benvc If i put any value lesser than 10, the list doesnt get all the data I want. I have no idea why, but what you are talking makes total sense. I will try out with lesser values and edit the output too

Comment: Question edited with outputs! @Kevin

Comment: Question edited with outputs! @benvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine as far as I can tell.
https://repl.it/repls/AgitatedNextInverse

However if you're just looking to find the second to last element, but getting stuck when your list is empty, add an if case:

```py
if len(lista)>=2:
    print(lista[-2])
```

But sounds list you can just catch it when your list reached the length you need

```py
if len(lista)==7:
    print(lista[6])
```

Comment: Perhaps you're getting caught by the difference between length (which starts at 1), and index (which starts at 0)? When the list length == 7, the last element is list[6]

Comment: Hi, Joe! thanks for your answer!
This, in theory, is exactly how i thought to do. But i feel like looping the "append" on the list makes python confused, since the list lenght will be x after looping x times. I will comment here the ouput I get with these lines.

Comment: Hi, Joe! With your second example in my code, the algorithm is still printing me the list just up until it has 3 elements. Then it stops (for whatever reason).
> Ring Alert Recebido > ['AT+SBDIX'] > ['AT+SBDIX', '+SBDIX: 0, 200, 1, 130, 11, 6'] > ['AT+SBDIX', '+SBDIX: 0, 200, 1, 130, 11, 6', 'OK']

Comment: I don't know why this is happening to you, but maybe you could put the 'if len(lista)==7:' logic AFTER the while loop instead of inside the while loop

Answer (score 0):

list indices begin at 0

**example**

```
lista = ['AT+SBDIX', '+SBDIX: 0, 196, 1, 126, 11, 5', 'OK', 'AT+SBDRT', '+SBDRT:', 'jupytertest', 'OK']


for index in range(0,7):
    print (index, lista[index])
```

**output (index, element**

```
0 AT+SBDIX
1 +SBDIX: 0, 196, 1, 126, 11, 5
2 OK
3 AT+SBDRT
4 +SBDRT:
5 jupytertest
6 OK
```

Comment: Hi, amchugh89! I'm using it like this, but the problem doesnt seem to be the algorithm printing the wrong element. Is not printing nothing at all (besides the list). Adding to my code the lines (> if len(lista) == 7: > print(lista[5])), my output stays like this:
```
Ring Alert recebido
['AT+SBDIX']
['AT+SBDIX', '+SBDIX: 0, 200, 1, 130, 11, 6']
['AT+SBDIX', '+SBDIX: 0, 200, 1, 130, 11, 6', 'OK']
```